# access-sql and VBA: SUM current month and year(february/2017) AND current month and last year (february/2016)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

i want to create a form in Access, which should sum number of sales of a product for current month and year, and for current month and last year.

the result should look like this:

ProductID, Sales16, Sales17

how should i proceed? So I get the desired result every month automatically with a click on the button in my Access tool. 
Maybe Combine vba-code with SQL-queries?

Given fields:
productid, dateofsale(dd:mm:yyyy), numberofsale, ...

im grateful for each help, tips,...

thank u ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you COULD go down this route why not use a Access Report? It'll group and aggregate your data from any query or table.

Forms should be used for entering and editing data. Reports should be used for displaying reports from your database. It'll save you alot of bother and you probably won't need any code given your simple requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
Select 
    productid, 
    Sum(IIf(dateofsale Between 
        DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1) And
        DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) + 1, 0), numberofsale, 0)) As
    totalthis,
    Sum(IIf(dateofsale Between 
        DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, Month(Date()), 1) And
        DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, Month(Date()) + 1, 0), numberofsale, 0)) As
    totallast
From
    YourTable
Group By
    productid
```